# QFT Fourier expansion of the fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory

This is probably a silly question, but I'm studying QFT and our professor did not give us a good explanation about this, why we can always expand the fields operator in terms of Fourier decomposition, I mean what's the physical interpretation about it? Is it some sort related to the wave function of quantum mechanics?

I thought that since i can "see" the field as a wave i can do it, because from a mathematical point of view it's just a bunch of sine, cosine, but i don't why this assumption holds

As usual thanks for any answer, have a good evening

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with QFT. It is simply always possible to Fourier decompose any function (subject to niceness properties that the function must have, which we always assume so in physics unless experiment proves this wrong).

Comment: shouldn't the function be periodic at least?

Comment: No. There is a lot of literature on the Fourier transform. You can look that up.

Comment: I guess i just mixed Fourier transform with series, my bad then, thank you

Comment: You can even define a Fourier series for non-periodic functions...just as an aside note.

Comment: that's new can you give me a link where i can read about it?

Comment: Well, it is just the reflection of the fact that the complex exponentials, appearing in the Fourier series, are an orthonormal basis for $L^2([a,b])$... I don't know any particular source. Try to search for "Fourier series non-periodic function" or "Riesz-Fischer theorem".

Comment: I'm sure you have computed a Fourier transform (FT) of a Gaussian distribution which is clearly not periodic (EDIT: I see I have misread the conversation, not relevant). Another side note; FT can be thought of as 'the' transformation whenever you have translational invariance. Similarly, you often decompose your objects into spherical harmonics whenever you have spherical symmetry. There's nothing wrong to think of it as just a convenient tool that helps us solve equations analytically.

Comment: Regarding references. Fourier series and Fourier transform is covered in many Physics books, often as part of field theory. You can find it in more generic mathematical references, e.g. [Arfken&Weber](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Methods-Physicists-7ed-Arfken/dp/9381269556/ref=pd_sbs_d_sccl_2_1/258-5401013-6750145?pd_rd_w=LdJ1n&content-id=amzn1.sym.c6c034f9-eec5-4242-a3bd-ae406477b5ce&pf_rd_p=c6c034f9-eec5-4242-a3bd-ae406477b5ce&pf_rd_r=2NGAQZ0ZE0CZD4D6XJPX&pd_rd_wg=K5jw4&pd_rd_r=f0e26579-ff09-412b-aaca-203dd26bc286&pd_rd_i=9381269556&psc=1).

Comment: If you want more depth, look for books on functional analysis and generalized functions, but IMHO Arfken&Weber (Ch 19,20) will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the answers i thought that being an L2 function had some particular physical propretry. Anyway I will go check the references, have a good day. ( I hope the message doesn't sound rude i m not a native speaker)